# Migrate data from Azure data lake in one subscription to another

Tags: azure, migration, azure-data-lake, azcopy

I have been looking for options to migrate data present in my ADLS in one subscription to ADLS in another subscription within Azure. I tried ADF for this purpose and it worked fine.

But the  copy speed is too slow in ADF. It copies at a speed of 10-15 KB/sec. Is there some way to increase speed of copy while using ADF?

Comment: Hi @Samyak Jain, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer.  This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way you can migrate data from Azure Data Lake between different subscription: [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction).

No matter Data Lake Gen1 or Gen2, Data Factory all support them as the [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview). Please ref these tutorials:

1. [Copy data to or from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store).
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Azure
   Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage).

You can create the source and sink dataset in different subscription through [linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#linked-service-properties):
[image]

But this option may cost you some money. You also could ref the Azure Az-copy tutorials: [Copy blobs between Azure storage accounts by using AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json).

Here is another blog [How To Copy Files From One Azure Storage Account To Another](https://charbelnemnom.com/how-to-transfer-data-from-one-azure-storage-account-to-another-account/):

- In this post, Bloger will outline how to copy data from one Azure
  Storage Account in one subscription to another Storage Account in
  another subscription.

These maybe what you're looking for.