# Failed to load one or more resources error when moving resources to different subscription

Tags: azure-storage-account, azure-rbac

I am performing move operation for resources in one subscription to another subscription.
I have resources like storage accounts, Key vaults etc in my subscription.

All resources are moving without any error except Data Lake Gen2 accounts.

I am getting this error while trying do the above:

```
Failed to load one or more resources due to no access, error code 403.
```

**I have owner role for both subscriptions.**
Why am I getting this error for Data Lake Gen2 accounts while I am able to perform move operation for storage accounts? What Am I missing? Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please **note** that, you cannot perform move operation on `Data Lake accounts`  as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftdatalake):**

[image]

According to the above, move operation of **`Data Lake accounts`**  to another **subscription** or resource group or region is not supported by Microsoft.

Before moving the resources to another subscription, please check whether the resource type is supported or not by referring to this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources).

You can raise a [**feature request**](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/) for the same.

**Alternatively**, you can migrate the Data from Azure Data Lake between subscriptions.
To do that please **refer** below link:

[migration - Migrate data from Azure data lake in one subscription to another by Leon Yue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820788/migrate-data-from-azure-data-lake-in-one-subscription-to-another)